# NativeScript RadListView image animation does not work

Tags: listview, nativescript, radlistview

I am trying to load images into NativeScript app using RadListView because it should have animation for images. Instead of animation when image is loaded, I see only a "blink" when image shows up.

I am using `http.getJSON` and when data is received UI renders the images.

My XML is here:

```
<lv:RadListView items="{{ myImagesObject }}" id="ls">
<lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
     <lv:ListViewLinearLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" itemInsertAnimation="Fade" itemDeleteAnimation="Slide"/>
</lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
<lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">

        <Image class="lista-katalozi-slika" id="slicice" stretch="aspectFill" src="{{ 'https://www.image_source.site/' + photo }}" /> 

    </StackLayout>
</lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
```

The thing is, when I scroll up and down, images are disappearing and showing up as a "blink". No animation at all. I am using pure js, no Typescript or Angular.

**UPDATE:**

Ok here is short video I recorded. https://mega.nz/#!FLBQlQ7Q!ynYnAmtELWPwZNr-dJFLbVu1tPjfm7_fAI8DVuvGFs0
It's more like image rendering/cashing problem. I have set fixed src to https://www.miffy.com/frontend/assets/img/icons/og-image-200x200.png and it is still happening even when it's same image. After loading the view, I switch off internet access and then try to scroll and images stops loading. I do not have problem with that to download them but when they I would like to add fade-in effect. Just to make it look nicer.

Comment: What do you mean by `animation` here? try this link https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=EtkUsj and let us know how do you feel aout it

Comment: Are these images loaded from url?

Comment: Hi yes they loaded from URL and URL is received as string in JSON. Ok here is short video I recorded. https://mega.nz/#!FLBQlQ7Q!ynYnAmtELWPwZNr-dJFLbVu1tPjfm7_fAI8DVuvGFs0
It's more like image rendering problem. I don't think that they get downloaded every single time. I have set fixed src to https://www.miffy.com/frontend/assets/img/icons/og-image-200x200.png and it is still happening even when it's same image.
Any ideas?